# Is there a way to gain access to the class of a method when all you have is a callable

Tags: python, methods, metaprogramming

I have code that is like:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        pass


class Bar:
    def foo(self):
        pass

f = random.choice((Foo().foo, Bar().foo))
```

How do I access `Bar` or `Foo` from f?

`f.__dict__` is of little to no help, but as `repr(f)` gives `<bound method Bar.foo of <__main__.Bar object at 0x10c6eec18>>'` it must be possible, but how?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Each bound method has the `__self__` attribute which is the

> instance to which this method is bound, or `None`

(copied from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members))

More about bound methods (from [*Data Model*](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html)):

> If you access a method (a function defined in a class namespace)
>   through an instance, you get a special object: a bound method (also
>   called instance method) object. ... Bound methods have two special
>   read-only attributes: `m.__self__` is the object on which the method
>   operates...

So `f.__self__` will get you the class instance:

```
print(f.__self__) # <__main__.Foo object at 0x7f766efeee48>
```

And `type(f.__self__)` or `f.__self__.__class__` will get you the type object:

```
print(type(f.__self__)) # <class '__main__.Foo'>
```

You'd only use `__class__` for [old-style classes](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#new-style-and-classic-classes).

Comment: Nitpick: The type of the instance isn't necessarily the class where the function was defined; just because the method is bound to an X instance doesn't mean the function couldn't be defined in class Y. But that said, this code will certainly produce the correct output in 99.99% of real-world scenarios. And anyway it's not clear what the OP's expected output would be in such a 0.01% case.